# Page request timed out while importint to MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Hellow

I have list with 30.000 objects that has to import to MySQL  (extern location) after 2 min I get following error:

'Request timed out.'

Website where file is upload is hosted on azure.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged `azure`? The error is rather obvious - the import is taking longer than your page's timeout. Increase the timeout. How you do that depends on the technology you used to build the page (ASP.NET ? PHP? Ruby?). Although 120 secs for a 30K line import is far too much.

Comment: How are you importing the rows? Using individual inserts (bad idea, extremely slow), batched statements, `LOAD DATA` ? What language, provider are you using? You should use the bulk import functionality of your provider instead of executing 30K insert statements

Comment: Language is asp.net. Reason for tagged Azure? Where in Azure can I change the timeout delay.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure. You'd get the same error if you run the site locally, or used a hoster. The timeout can be set either in web.config or with a page directive **BUT** the real problem is the insertion code. 120 secs is *too much* for only 30K rows.

Comment: I have the problem NOT locally. In the 2 min there are 800 inserts then I get the error and stops with inserts.

Comment: Which means that you need to debug that code. You haven't posted the code though, so it's impossible to help. Maybe that other MySQL server is too slow, maybe it runs on a micro instance. 3 inserts/sec is atrocious though. What is the file format? How are you inserting the rows?

Comment: Following code doesn't work <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration> in web.config

Comment: No wonder - with 3 inserts/sec you'd need at least 10000 seconds - over 2 hours. Post the *code you are using to insert the data*.

Answer (score 0):

BNILIJST.BLL.Klanten.Update(i, kc.FirmaNaam, kc.BtwNummer, kc.Straat, kc.Postcode, kc.Gemeente, kc.Bni_Klant, kc.Actief, kc.UpdateDate);

This is the insert Statement

With the code is nothing wrong, Exept it can faster but time is not a problem it runs at night.

I want changhe the time of sending request in azure